# Elegant solution for proxy mess

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

In Java 8, I wanted to write a class that, given one or more listeners, would return a proxied List (using implementation of List of my choosing by passing in its class) that triggers the listener whenever something is added or removed.  The code (bear with me) is below:

```java
public final class EventedList {
    private EventedList() {
    }

    protected static class ListInvocationHandler<T> implements InvocationHandler {
        private List<T> theList;
        private ListChangeHandler<T>[] listeners;

        public ListInvocationHandler(Class<? extends List<T>> listClass, ListChangeHandler<T>[] listeners) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
            this.listeners = listeners;
            theList = listClass.newInstance();
        }

        public Object invoke(Object self, Method method, Object[] args)
                throws Throwable {
            Object ret = method.invoke(theList, args);
            switch(method.getName()) {
            case "add": 
                trigger((T)args[0], true);
                break;
            case "remove":
                if(args[0] instanceof Integer) {
                    trigger((T)ret, false);
                } else {
                    trigger((T)args[0], false);
                }
                break;
            }
            return ret;
        }

        public void trigger(T obj, boolean added) {
            Arrays.stream(listeners).forEachOrdered(l -> l.onChange(obj, added));
        }
    }

    public static <T, U extends List<T>> List<T> newList(Class<U> listClass, ListChangeHandler<T> ... listeners) throws IllegalArgumentException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<T> obj = (List<T>)Proxy.newProxyInstance(listClass.getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[]{List.class}, new ListInvocationHandler<T>(listClass, listeners));
        return obj;
    }

    public static <T, U extends List<T>> List<T> newListSafe(Class<U> listClass, ListChangeHandler<T> ... listeners) {
        List<T> obj = null;
        try {
            obj = newList(listClass, listeners);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | InstantiationException
                | IllegalAccessException e) {
        }
        return obj;
    }   
}
```

It works, but it is certainly not without its issues.

1. I initially only had one type T, but I was getting errors using `Class<? extends List<T>>` so I use U to represent `? extends List<T>` instead.
2. In invoke method of `ListInvocationHandler`, I'm having to forcively cast `Object` to `T`.  I think that is unavoidable, but I welcome any alternatives.
3. `newProxyInstance` is returning `Object` that I'm having to cast to `List`.  Also this I believe is unavoidable but I welcome any alternatives.
4. I'm receiving a "Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter listeners" warning on listeners parameters presumably because they are variable parameter arguments, however I don't see the obvious risk of doing it this way.

The main that I'm using is the following:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = EventedList.newListSafe(ArrayList.class, new ListChangeHandler<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onChange(String value, boolean added) {
            System.out.println(value + ", " + (added ? "added" : "removed"));
        }

    });

    list.add("Badger");                                  // Badger, added
    list.add("Badger");                                  // Badger, added
    list.add("Badger");                                  // Badger, added
    list.add("Badger");                                  // Badger, added
    list.remove("Badger");                               // Badger, removed
    list.add("Mushroom");                                // Mushroom, added
    list.remove("Mushroom");                             // Mushroom, removed

    // [Badger, Badger, Badger]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));  
}
```

5. The main itself calling the method has a nice type safety warning, even if the parameters should be implicit.
6. If at all possible, I would like to be able to call it as follows (though I'm receiving an error as such):

   ```
   List<String> list = EventedList.newListSafe(ArrayList.class, (value, added) -> {
       System.out.println(value + ", " + (added ? "added" : "removed"));
   });
   ```

I apologize for the wall of text.  I appreciate any input.

Comment: Why not provide a supplier instead: `EventedList.newList(ArrayList::new, ...)` and avoid the reflection mess?

Comment: Why don't you just use delegation and pass a new list to the constructor?

Comment: @assylias I didn't even consider using a Supplier, but that is a decent idea, thank you.

Comment: @Thomas I would have preferred to not convert a list since everyone with the old instance won't cause the triggers in the proxy.  Of course if I could modify that instance to cause triggers, that would be better still.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: If you control the class where you perform the add or remove is there any reason not to trigger the listener inside them?

Comment: @jclozano Not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: I would ask, do you control the class where the Add and Remove methods are located?

Comment: If you do, why dont you trigger the listener inside them

Comment: @jclozano You mean *implement* add and remove and trigger it when called as  Thomas's answer would do?

Comment: I do mean it, but only if he can extend the proper class, otherwise my comment would not be applicable

Comment: @jclozano I have full control of all classes that aren't part of the jvm standard.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a decorator instead and probably get rid of (almost) all those warnings:

```
class EventedList<E> implements List<E> {
  private List<E> delegate;
  private List<ListChangeHandler<E>> listeners;  

  //using varargs here would still cause the heap pollution warning 
  public EventedList( List<E> d, ListChangeHandler<E>... l ) {
    //set and initialize
  }

  public boolean add(E e) {
    delegate.add(e);
    trigger(e);
  }

  ... //other methods

  private void trigger(E e) {
    //trigger listeners
  }
```

Then just call it like this

```
List<String> list = new EventedList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(), 
                                            new ListChangeHandler<String>() { ... } );
```

... or create a factory method.

Comment: While I value this solution and it is likely what I would do if I had to write it at work, I'm purposefully trying to make use of Proxies for this task to see if an elegant solution using proxies existed.

Comment: @Neil as far as I understand `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` are more or less a special form of decorator (with some additional properties) but you'd still have to wrap it around the list instances that are being created. If you can't change old code that is using lists you want to proxy you couldn't use proxies as well - so you're in the same situation as with a normal decorator. In that case you'd have to use AOP to apply the decoration at load time to also decorate existing lists.

Comment: I suppose that's why Proxy is going out of fashion.  ;)

Comment: @Neil probably ... though most AOP frameworks have their own form of proxy. The main question would be: which benefits would using `Proxy` have that justify having more complex and possibly messy (and thus fragile) code? :)

Comment: A proxy is useful when you want to support arbitrary interfaces, treat different methods uniformly or are dealing with types not known at compile time. Since in this case, you are dealing with exactly one interface, `List`, known at compile-time, and have a switch over the method name in your proxy, none of these three possible reasons applies so this answer is *the* answer.